# WPF userControl containing an image image doesnt resize when usercontrol is resized

Tags: c#, wpf, image, visual-studio, adorner

I am working in wpf. I have a userControl in which sits an Image control.

I add a BitmapImage to this userControl through image.source.

This userControl is then added to a canvas, any control attached to this canvas has adorners attached so that each of the four corners can be dragged to resize the userControl.

My problem is, is that the bitmap doesnt resize with the userControl.

Is there an easy way to make the bitmap redraw when the userControl resizes?

Here is the XAML for the user control:

```
<UserControl x:Name="cusImageControl" x:Class="StoryboardTool.CustomImage"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" BorderThickness="0" MouseDown="cusImageControl_MouseDown">
    <Image x:Name="image"  >
        <Image.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem x:Name="ContextMenuBringForward" Header="BringForward" Click="ContextMenuBringForward_Click"/>
                <MenuItem x:Name="ContextMenuSendBackward" Header="SendBackward" Click="ContextMenuSendBackward_Click"/>
            </ContextMenu>
        </Image.ContextMenu>
    </Image>
</UserControl>

public void chooseImage()
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.Title = "Choose Image to Add";

            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                BitmapImage bImage = new BitmapImage();
                bImage.BeginInit();
                bImage.UriSource = new Uri(ofd.FileName);
                bImage.EndInit();

                image.Width = bImage.Width;
                image.Height = bImage.Height;
                image.Source = bImage;
                //image.Stretch = Stretch.Fill;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you have mentioned the dimensions(width, height) in the usercontrol?

Comment: Can you show us your XAML code?

Comment: Added the XAML for the UserControl, and the method in which I choose the image.

Comment: What's about image scale mode? ex: <Image Stretch="Fill" Margin="0"/>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be setting a width and height in your code behind... this is the size that the `Image` will be. Instead of this, try setting the `Image.Source` property in xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.UserControl1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    mc:Ignorable="d" 
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Image Source="/WpfApplication1;component/Images/ImageName.png" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

If I put this into `MainWindow.xaml`, the `Image` resizes when resizing the Window.

If you need to set the URL of the `Image` in code, then you can add a property in your view model, bind it to the `Source` property and change that to the new path in code instead:

```
<Image Source="{Binding ViewModelSourceProperty}" /> // don't set size here
```

I hope that helps.